# How to place text on top of dodged columns?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a dataframe of housing data, but had to make another dataframe where need to sum the housing type depend on where the area of the house, which there are 2 types of houses in 3 different areas.

```
df <- na.omit(n[, c("matssvaedi", "teg_eign_s_i")])
counts <- df %>%
  group_by(matssvaedi, teg_eign_s_i)%>%
  summarise(count = n())
df1 <- ggplot(counts, aes(x = matssvaedi, y = count))
df1 + geom_bar(aes(fill = teg_eign_s_i), stat = "identity", position = 'dodge') + geom_text(aes(label = count), color="black",vjust = 0.01, size = 3) + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired") + theme_classic()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your question is "how do I position the text on top of the corresponding bar?". In that case, you can add a position argument to `geom_text()` in the same way you specify a position for `geom_bar()`. For example, see this small reprex:

```
counts <- mtcars |> 
  group_by(cyl, vs) |> 
  summarise(count = n())
df1 <- ggplot(counts, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = factor(count)))
df1 + geom_bar(aes(fill = vs), stat = "identity", position = 'dodge') + 
  geom_text(aes(label = count, group = vs,), 
            position = position_dodge(width = .9),
            color="black",vjust = 0.01, size = 3)
```

You can use the `vjust` argument in `geom_text()` to move the text slightly higher or lower depending on what you want. This gives:

[image: Bar chart]

Comment: important to mention that the standard dodge is .9 in `position_dodge()`. I'd generally avoid combining methods `position = "dodge"` and `position = position_dodge()` for exactly that reason that you might get unexpected results.

Comment: and another small extra comment: (fighting windmills here): instead of geom_bar(stat = "identity") you can use the shorter and easier to read: `geom_col()`

Comment: Thankyou for the help. and @tjebo, what is teh different interms of position = "dodge" and osition = position_dodge()?

Comment: @NouvanShebubakar position = "dodge" is simply a shorthand for convenience that invokes the function position_dodge with its defaults (i.e., it is equivalent to position = position_dodge(). However, using the latter might come with different arguments (e.g., a different dodge), which you are not able to pass to the first.